# How could I kill all task of "abc.exe" EXCEPT the ones with specific PIDs?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm automating massive file saving via Chrome, and I need to keep the one Chrome window I auth-ed in to keep working, but after 100 page loads Chrome eats up 15GB of ram.

Saving the PID list at first is ok. But I need an efficient way to kill all the other PIDs except the original

```
Get-Process | Select -ExpandProperty Id
```

I use this to get the PID list (at first it saves to a file)

The other running code is basically in a loop

```
start chrome --new-window nextLINK
```

My goal is to when about 101 chrome windows are open I want to kill all except the first.

Comment: `gps chrome | ? {$_.id -notin (PID1,PID2,...PIDX)} | spps -whatif`

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` might be a better approach than trying to automate a browser.

Comment: I tried it. It won't close any of the windows, but it will unload all pages displaying a chrome error message

Comment: @DirtyFred - what did you try? Invoke-Webrequest or spps?

Comment: The answer I gave *is* a solution to your question but apparently, killing PID's is not the way to [kill chrome tabs](https://superuser.com/q/306714/6825). I assume you should look at Chrome automation but that's an entirely different question.